# how call various function based on the value of $route.path?

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs2, vue-router

I am fairly new to vue.

Lets say, this is my URL: `https://mywebsite.com/states/ABC?query=` and `https://mywebsite.com/search?query=`

I am grabbing the path `/states/ABC` and `/search` using `$route.path`. I am doing this path inside `mounted()`

Now, based on this value of the `$route.path`, I want to fire different methods eg if it's `states` then `statesEvent()` and if it's `search`, then `searchEvent`.

**EDITED**: both these events are present in a mixin. I am loading that mixin into this component.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should use named routes and `name` instead of `path`. It'll make your life easier. Reference: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

Comment: @Ayrton the functions which I need to fire based on the value from route.path are present in a seperate mixin. I just to need to call these functions from this component. Moreover, the `name` is `null` in my case.

Comment: So what's wrong with `if(this.$route.path.startsWith('/states')) { doSomething... }`?

Comment: thanks. I had no clue that I could do something like `startsWith('/states') {...}` .. cheers !!

Comment: @NaumanTanwir I put it in an answer so you can mark the question as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$route.path` is a simple String you can match on with any of Javascripts string matching operators (from `==` to `match(/regex/)` to `includes` etc.).

In your particular case I'd suggest to go with

```
const path = this.$route.path
if(path.startsWith('/states') {
  // execute states specific code
}
else if(path.startsWith('/search')) {
  // search specific code
}
```